# Safest way to detect user country on Windows

Tags: windows

I'm trying to find a (pretty) reliable way to detect a user's country on a Windows system without using geo-location services. It needs to work in offline mode.

What I do now is check the registry for a few settings. I'm especially interested in identifying users from the US.

HKCU: Control Panel\International\sCurrency - check for "$"
HKCU, Control Panel\International\iCountry - check for 1

Any better ways, or any additional values to check to filter out non-US users from the check?

Comment: Is time zone close enough most people like there clock to be right?

Comment: Time zone check is actually a very good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using .Net?

```
using System.Globalization;
string name = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.DisplayName;
```

This should provide the name of the country.

Comment: I know how to get the display name, but thanks anyway. My goal is to try determine if it is a "real" US user, or just a OEM install using default US values.